# How can I return a distinct array of date ordered documents?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

In mongodb I have a `locations` collection which houses data about where a person has been.

I have an `operatorID` field, a `location` object, and an `updatedAt` ISODate field.

e.g.

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("..."), "location" : [object Object], "operatorID" : "T800", "updatedAt"  : ISODate("2015-01-08T10:54:32.389Z") }
{"_id" : ObjectId("..."), "location" : [object Object], "operatorID" : "T800", "updatedAt"  : ISODate("2015-01-08T11:00:15.304Z") }
{"_id" : ObjectId("..."), "location" : [object Object], "operatorID" : "T1000", "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-01-09T14:50:32.129Z") }
{"_id" : ObjectId("..."), "location" : [object Object], "operatorID" : "T1000", "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-01-10T13:10:15.204Z") }
{"_id" : ObjectId("..."), "location" : [object Object], "operatorID" : "T100", "updatedAt"  : ISODate("2015-01-25T14:50:32.129Z") }
{"_id" : ObjectId("..."), "location" : [object Object], "operatorID" : "T100", "updatedAt"  : ISODate("2015-01-24T13:10:15.204Z") }
```

Given an array of names, how can I return an array of the most recent unique operator ID's sorted by `updatedAt:1`?

e.g: Given `{ operatorID: { $in: ["T1000", T800"] } }`

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("222"), "location" : [object Object], "operatorID" : "T800", "updatedAt"  : ISODate("2015-01-08T11:00:15.304Z") }
{"_id" : ObjectId("333"), "location" : [object Object], "operatorID" : "T1000", "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-01-09T14:50:32.129Z") }
```

I have been trying this in the shell which get's me most of the way there, but I essentially just need to return the last object within each group of operatorID's:

```
db.locations.find( { $query: {'operatorID': { $in: ["T1000", "T800"] } }, $orderby: { operatorID:1, updatedAt:1 } } )
```

and

```
db.locations.find( { operatorID: { $in: ["T1000", "T800"] }  } ).sort( { operatorID:1, updatedAt:1 } )
```

Both of which return all T1000 and T800's sorted by name and date in their respective groups.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a good idea to keep track of this info in a small side collection, but with your current collection you can use an aggregation:

```
db.locations.aggregate([
    { "$sort" : { "updatedAt" : -1 } },
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "$operatorID", "updatedAt" : { "$first" : "$updatedAt" } } }
])
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this it and mark it off later today.